# Are these right-shift operator examples correct?

Tags: javascript

The right-shift operator examples on the MDN for both, the:

1. Right-shift operator; and
2. Unsigned right-shift operator

just don't make sense to me. They not only challenge my understanding of two's complement, they also confuse my mind about their own function. Am I missing something or do these examples need correction?

The confusing examples with a commentary as to what I expected are produced below.

1. #### [Right-shift operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Right_shift_assignment)

   The example with negative numbers for the right-shift operator reads:

   `var bar -5; //    (-00000000000000000000000000000101)`

   `bar >>= 2;  // -2 (-00000000000000000000000000000010)`

   First of all, assuming DWORD size (32-bit, signed), the two's complement representation of `-5` is `11111111111111111111111111111011`. And I don't even know what that representation `(-00000000000000000000000000000101)` provided in the example above means.

   Secondly, if I were to infer its meaning from just reading the example, it probably is saying:

   *Take the positive representation of the first operand, shift it second operand number of places to the right, convert that to its decimal, and then re-apply any sign, whether positive or negative, to the result.*

   However, I tried that, too, and by that explanation, the result should be `-1` and not `-2` as follows.

   `var bar -5; //    (-00000000000000000000000000000101)`

   `bar >>= 2;  // -1 (-00000000000000000000000000000001)`

   So, to test the example, I typed the following JavaScript code, and lo! it produced exactly what the documented example purports.

   `console.log(5 >> 2) // produces -2`

   What's going on?
2. #### [Unsigned Right-Shift Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift_assignment)

   The example with negative numbers reads:

   `var bar = -5; // (-00000000000000000000000000000101)`

   `bar >>>= 2; // 1073741822 (00111111111111111111111111111110)`

   With this one, the only gripe I have is that the binary representation of          `-5` is wrong. If that is corrected, then the example makes complete sense. The correct example would be as follows:

   `var bar = -5; // (11111111111111111111111111111011)`

   `bar >>>= 2; // 1073741822 (00111111111111111111111111111110)`

   As you can see above, the right-shifting of `11111111111111111111111111111011` by two places would yield `00111111111111111111111111111110`, which would yield the positive number `1073741822`.

   I tried it and it produces the right result:

   `console.log(5 >>> 2); // produces 1073741822`

   This one, I assume, is just a typographical error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Ignore the binary representation, as it is not very helpful. It is literally the signed binary representation, which doesn't really exist in the computer, since computers represent signed numbers as two's complement, not as signed binary.

`-5` is represented, as you say, as `...11111011` (`~4`). Shift it twice right, while copying the MSB to preserve the sign, and you get `...11111110` (`~1`), which is the representation of `-2`.

2) Again, the binary representation of `-5` is *correct* but not *useful*, since that's *not the representation the computer uses*. For human mathematics, `+5(10)` is same as `+101(2)`, and `-5(10)` is same as `-101(2)`; but computers represent them as `...00000101` and `...11111011`, respectively.

Comment: Could you please provide a step-by-step for (1). I am getting the decimal `-66` if I preserve the MSB and shift 2 places to the right.

Comment: How do you get 66?

Comment: Sorry, this time I got `-98`. I shifted `1111 1011` (-5 base 10) 2 places to the right except for the MSB. I got `1001 1110` (-98 base 10).

Comment: That's not how it works. Right shift without copying MSB (`>>>`) would just introduce a `0` from left side: `0b11111011 >>> 2 = 0b00111110`. The MSB-preserving shift (`>>`) copies MSB to next one instead; so (assuming we're on 8-bit architecture), you'd get `0b11111011 >> 2 = 0b11111110`, not `10011110`. I.e. because MSB is `1`, `>> 2` introduces two `1`s in front instead two `0`s, like `>>> 2` would.

Comment: For the `>>`, you mean, in addition to preserving the MSB, it copies what was in the MSB into each of the places we need to pad, padding them with the MSB instead of padding them with zeros?

Comment: Thank you. Your edit to your previous comment answered my previous comment question.

Comment: Yup. Also, note that `-101` (human-readable binary) is what you get when you ask JavaScript: `(-5).toString(2)`. There is no easy way to get underlying binary from JS.

Comment: `const bin = n => Array.from({length:32}, e => { let z = n; n >>>= 1; return z; }).reduce((a, e) => (e&1) + a, "")` so you can see under the hood. `bin(-5)` comes as `"11111111111111111111111111111011"`.

Answer (score 1):

The examples provided by MDN are confusing because they do not show the real binary representation of the negative numbers.

The binary representation of `-5` is `111...11111011` (fill the ellipsis with `1` to reach the total length of `32` bits).

### >>

The regular [right shift operator (`>>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Right_shift) (also known as "sign-propagating shift" and ["arithmetic shift"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift)) shifts the bits to the right, discards the rightmost bits and uses the value of the leftmost bit to fill the newly freed positions on the left.

In the two's complement binary representation (used by most computers nowadays), the leftmost bit is the sign bit. It is `0` for positive numbers and `0` and `1` for negative numbers.

The two's complement binary representation of `-5` is:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+----------+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ........ | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
+---+---+---+---+---+----------+---+---+---+---+---+
|                                          |       |
   \------------------------------------/    ^   ^
  ^     these bits moves to the right        +---+------ these 2 bits are discarded
  |
  +---- the value of this bit is used to fill the 2 leftmost freed positions
```

`-5 >> 2` is `111...11111110` which is the binary representation of `-2`.

### >>>

The [unsigned right shift operator (`>>>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift) (also know as "zero-fill right shift" and ["logical right shift"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift)) also shifts the bits to the right and discards the rightmost bits but it always uses `0` to fill the freed positions on the left.

`-5 >>> 2` is `00111...11111110` which is the positive number `1073741822` (`=2^30-2`)

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you. :-)